# Change .text section to an address lower than the default address

Tags: linux, linker

I am trying to link with a specific .text section address(which is lower than the default address 0x08048000 for linux/x86 ),

```
"gcc -Ttext 0x00849a40"
```

the program compile, link and run without any problem, but When I try with a different address :

```
"gcc -Ttext 0x00840000"
```

the program will gives a segmentation fault.

if I try any address above 0x00840000 from which does not conflict with the other section, e.g.

```
 "gcc -Ttext 0x09000000" or "gcc -Ttext 0x091111111"
```

the program also compile, link and run without any problem.

I understand that:

- **0x08048000** is the default address on which ld starts the first **PT_LOAD** segment on Linux/x86. On Linux/amd64 the default is **0x400000** and you can change the default by using a custom linker script.
- I check with "/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr" is 0x10000 and the "/proc/self/maps" to make sure the .text section wont use any of the above memory address.
- the text section should be aligned to 16, both of the above address 0x00849a40 and 0x00840000 is.

So My question is :

- Is it allowed to use section-start address lower than the default value?(I believe it is allowed)
- Is there any requirement when using a different section start address?

Comment: You should take in account the other sections as well.

Comment: I think `linker script` may help you place sections as you want - https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Scripts.html,